# Issue trying to print table across whole page without printing on the next one with IEEEtran

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I have the following table I want to span across the two main text columns in IEEEtran, however, whenever I try to print it, the table goes on to the  next page. I have tried the H specifier but it makes the table disappear. What can I do? Could somebody please help me out?

```
\begin{table*}{h!}
\centering
\caption{BTC dataset sample (last five rows)}
\label{tab:dataset}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
time          & timeDate   & close    & high     & low      & open     & volumefrom & volumeto      \\ \hline
1682985600000 & 2023-05-02 & 28694.85 & 28896.62 & 27897.95 & 28086.19 & 32635.23   & 927167494.21  \\ \hline
1683072000000 & 2023-05-03 & 29041    & 29274.35 & 28155.84 & 28694.85 & 40240.91   & 1150094643.14 \\ \hline
1683158400000 & 2023-05-04 & 28866.54 & 29370.41 & 28703.83 & 29041    & 27555.47   & 798614954.67  \\ \hline
1683244800000 & 2023-05-05 & 29550.84 & 29697.23 & 28853.1  & 28866.54 & 35357.4    & 1037025191.1  \\ \hline
1683331200000 & 2023-05-06 & 28845.45 & 29857.86 & 28459.77 & 29550.84 & 23039.88   & 670625654.68  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. IEEE dooesnt alow to have images on the first page, `figure*` always appear on the top of the next page from where is inserted. You may try to use package `stfloats` which enable that `figure*` can appear at top or bottom of the page where is asserted

Answer (score 1):

@Zarko has already pointed out in a comment that if the `twocolumn` option is is in effect (as is the case by default for the `IEEEtran` document class), LaTeX *always* places double-wide floats, i.e., `figure*` and `table*` environments, at the *top of a page*. While this may seem to be needlessly constraining at first, there are excellent typographical reasons for imposing this constraint. The chief advantage is legibility.

There *is* something you can do, though: Make the table more attractive from a visual/aesthetic point of view. The purpose of this action is to entice the readers of your document to actually spend more than about twelve milliseconds glancing at the table.

- The first improvement would be to give the table a more open and inviting "looK". This may be achieved by getting rid of all vertical lines or "rules" and using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines or "rules". This may be achieved with the help of the user macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.
- The second improvement would be to align the numbers in columns 3 thru 8 on their decimal markers. This may be achieved with the help of the `S` column type provided by the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

I trust you will agree with me that taking these simple measures can have a major effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman for both text and math material
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{before}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
time          & timeDate   & close    & high     & low      & open     & volumefrom & volumeto      \\ \hline
1682985600000 & 2023-05-02 & 28694.85 & 28896.62 & 27897.95 & 28086.19 & 32635.23   & 927167494.21  \\ \hline
1683072000000 & 2023-05-03 & 29041    & 29274.35 & 28155.84 & 28694.85 & 40240.91   & 1150094643.14 \\ \hline
1683158400000 & 2023-05-04 & 28866.54 & 29370.41 & 28703.83 & 29041    & 27555.47   & 798614954.67  \\ \hline
1683244800000 & 2023-05-05 & 29550.84 & 29697.23 & 28853.1  & 28866.54 & 35357.4    & 1037025191.1  \\ \hline
1683331200000 & 2023-05-06 & 28845.45 & 29857.86 & 28459.77 & 29550.84 & 23039.88   & 670625654.68  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\caption{after}
\begin{tabular}{@{} 
                l l 
                *{5}{S[table-format= 5.2]} 
                     S[table-format=10.2] 
                @{}}
\toprule
time & date & {close} & {high} & {low} & {open} & {volumefrom} & {volumeto} \\ \midrule
1682985600000 & 2023-05-02 & 28694.85 & 28896.62 & 27897.95 & 28086.19 & 32635.23   & 927167494.21  \\ 
1683072000000 & 2023-05-03 & 29041    & 29274.35 & 28155.84 & 28694.85 & 40240.91   & 1150094643.14 \\ 
1683158400000 & 2023-05-04 & 28866.54 & 29370.41 & 28703.83 & 29041    & 27555.47   & 798614954.67  \\ 
1683244800000 & 2023-05-05 & 29550.84 & 29697.23 & 28853.1  & 28866.54 & 35357.4    & 1037025191.1  \\ 
1683331200000 & 2023-05-06 & 28845.45 & 29857.86 & 28459.77 & 29550.84 & 23039.88   & 670625654.68  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```